# How to minimize a gap between primary and secondary axis columns (in bar chart) without making it thick IN EXCEL?

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I want to make two columns (primary and secondary axis -- grey and green) closer for each year. That the bigger gap would be not between primary and secondary axis columns, but between each year. I tried "gap width", but it just makes it thick
[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to adjust the "series overlap" option instead. It should be near the setting for adjusting the gap width.

Comment: It's not working, because the darker columns inside were put there like this. If I change series overlap into something less than 100% it gets out. I need all column with the darker columns inside to get closer

Comment: Not sure how your data look, but can you add a row between your years? That should add space.

Comment: Right, now it is better, I have a bigger gap now between the years, but the gap between grey and green columns are still the same. It may be enough, if there is no other way. Thanks!